# docker Reset to factory defaults by mistake

Tags: docker

I just reset my docker setting by default which cause I can't find my docker images anymore, it's so confusing, I have my mysql db and Mongodb over there.

Is there anyway can't help to recover my docker images and container id? Many thanks!!!

Comment: I was using docker desktop on my Mac Pro, and it can't restart when I upgrade my MacOS from Catalina to Big Sur, so I followed the instruction on the dialogue by "Reset to factory defaults", but still failed to restart and noticed "data missing", it also can't upgrade from the notice popup because of the restart failed problem. I just download the latest intel chip version and restart successfully, but the images and containers have gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're in a fix. Let's try to understand where we're at right now.

Rightfully said by @maxweil, there is no way to get restore containers and images if you **pruned** your Docker setup. You can only rebuild or pull.
Please tell us the exact command that you used.

Yet, assuming that you did actually **prune** it all, you can try to fetch all your Docker images and containers back to your system.

If your CLI history is still available, use the following command to fetch all previous Docker commands that you've run.

```
history | grep docker
```

Cherry pick the specific ones that you want to restore, run them again, and you'll have them all back.

If you used a **Dockerfile** or a **docker-compose.yaml** file, you can directly run them again, and Docker will build them back.

Answer (score 0):

If you deleted all your local containers and images, e.g. using the `docker system prune` command, there is no easy way to recover them.
You have to pull the images again from the container registry.